# Asp.Net WebApi OData: Mapping entity property to atom

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, odata

With the old `System.Data.Services.DataService<T>` it is possible to map properties on an entity class using `System.Data.Services.Common.EntityPropertyMappingAttribute` as in this example:

```
using System;
using System.Data.Services.Common;

namespace NuGet.Lucene.Web.DataServices
{
  [EntityPropertyMapping("Id", SyndicationItemProperty.Title, SyndicationTextContentKind.Plaintext, keepInContent: false)]
  public class MyEntity
  {
    public string Id { get; set; }
  }
}
```

This would result in the property `Id` being included in the `title` element when the content type is `application/atom+xml`.

WebApi OData seems to ignore this attribute and the rendered `title` element is empty.

Is there a way to do something similar with WebApi OData?

Comment: Could you please share the payload that contains "title"?

Comment: Here's an example using WCF Data Services that contains title: https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/Packages()?$top=1 and here is example output from WebApi OData that has an empty title: http://dpaste.com/hold/1793064/

Comment: As far as I know, Atom format is not part of OASIS OData protocol, and WebApi OData team put more emphasis on Json. So switching to Json may be a good idea.

Comment: I'm building an API where the (old) client only speaks atom+xml. It turns out mapping these properties is not actually required, but I was curious if there was a way to do it in WebApi OData.